# Zoom on scroll interaction in figma

Tags: frontend, figma, wireframe

I want to build a figma prototype that will allow users to zoom in and out from one photo to another using scrolling/pinch on trackpad.
I can also make a huge photo to zoom in and out of it.
The idea is to make an interface in which zooming in and out will change photos
Any thoughts of how to do it?
Wireframe demonstration below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5tRC.jpg)